# How can I set value for "Found In" Attribute for a RTC workitem?

Tags: java, api, attributes, rtc, workitem

I am trying to create and update a RTC workitem by using plain Java API.
I am able to set most of the attributes I need except "Found In".

I tried something like:

IAttribute FoundInAttribute = workItemClient.findAttribute(projectArea, "Found In" , null); 
wc.getWorkItem().setValue(FoundInAttribute, "The value I want to set");

And I got an exception saying setValue() is expecting an IDeliverableHandle object rather than String.

How can I get the IDeliverableHandle I need?

Thanks,
Kane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OP Kane Zeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220271/kane-zeng) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790940/how-can-i-set-value-for-found-in-attribute-for-a-rtc-workitem/22792499#comment34771066_22792499) that, out of the following solutions below, one is working:

> I use:

```java
IDeliverableHandle deliverable = 
   workItemClient.findDeliverableByName(projectArea, currentFoundIn,
   IDeliverable.SMALL_PROFILE ,null);
```

> and I can get what I need now

---

Original answer:

[That thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/10383/programmatic-workitem-documentation) mentions:

```java
IDeliverableHandle deliverable= ... // Find a deliverable using one of
the IWorkItemClient#findDeliverable* methods

IAttribute foundIn= workItemClient.findAttribute(project,
  IWorkItem.FOUND_IN_PROPRTY, monitor);
workItem.setValue(foundIn, deliverable);
```

That seems similar to [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/13501/how-to-get-the-found-in-attribute-for-a-work-item):

> The attributes can be acquired using

```java
IWorkItemCommon#findAttribute(IProjectAreaHandle projectArea, 
  String attributeId, IProgressMonitor monitor);
```

> So for the Found In attribute, you would do the following

```java
IAttribute foundIn= workItemClient.findAttribute(projectArea,
  IWorkItem.FOUND_IN_PROPERTY, monitor);
IDeliverableHandle deliverable = (IDeliverableHandle)workItem.getValue(foundIn);
```

A [more recent answer](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/137898/how-to-get-the-found-in-field-from-an-rtc-defect-type-work-item-using-the-java-api) gives:

```java
IAttribute foundInAttribute = myWorkItemClient.findAttribute(projectAreaHandle, "foundIn" , null);
IDeliverableHandle foundInDeliverableHandle = (IDeliverableHandle) currentWI.getValue(foundInAttribute);
if (foundInDeliverableHandle != null){
    IDeliverable deliverable = (IDeliverable) this.repository.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(foundInDeliverableHandle, IItemManager.DEFAULT, null);
}
```

(you would find a [similar approach there](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/84545/how-to-get-work-item-found-in-attribute-value))

Comment: Thanks, The first one did help. I use `IDeliverableHandle deliverable= workItemClient.findDeliverableByName(projectArea, currentFoundIn ,IDeliverable.SMALL_PROFILE ,null);` and I can get what I need now

Comment: @KaneZeng Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.